# linux ubuntu : can't make modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I am trying to learn Kernel Module programming. I have configured options by the `make menuconfig` command (seems that if I undo my operations the error still exists).

But under `"/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic"` , while entering `"make modules"`,I got :

```
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
```

I tried to add a file named syscall_32.tbl but another required file pops out. Is there any library or package that needs to be installed?

Comment: so you're working as root, right ? you shouldn't do that, copy linux sources in your $HOME and work from here

Comment: @Mali work from user root did help!But why working as root will cause that error?